# Best way to iterate over a byte/unicode string in Cython

Tags: python, c, string, unicode, cython

<sub>I'm just beginning with Cython and it also turns out very hard to google Cython-specific stuff, so sorry in advance.</sub>

I am re-implementing a Python function with Cython. It pretty much looks like this in Python:

```
def func(s, numbers=None):
    if numbers:
         some_dict = numbers
    else:
         some_dict = default
    return sum(some_dict[c] for c in s)
```

And it works fine on Python 2 and 3. But if I try to type `s` and `c`, it breaks on at least one of Python versions. I tried:

```
def func(char *s, numbers=None):
    if numbers:
         some_dict = numbers
    else:
         some_dict = default
    cdef char c
    cdef double m = 0.0
    for c in s:
        m += some_dict[<bytes>c]
    return m
```

This is the only thing I got to work at all, to be honest, and it gives a decent speedup on Python 2, but breaks on Python 3. Having read [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html#iteration) piece of Cython docs, I thought the following would work on Python 3:

```
def func(unicode s, numbers=None):
    if numbers:
         some_dict = numbers
    else:
         some_dict = default
    cdef double m = 0.0
    for c in s:
        m += some_dict[c]
    return m
```

but it actually raises a `KeyError` and it seems like `c` is still a `char` (the missing key is `80` if `s` starts with a `'P'`) but when I `print(type(c))` it says `<class 'str'>`.

Note that the original untyped code works under both versions but is about twice slower than the working typed version on Python 2.

So how do I make it work on Python 3 at all, and then how do I get it to work on both Python versions at once? Can/should I wrap type declarations in type/version checks? Or should I maybe write two functions and conditionally assign one of them to a publicly available name?

P.S. I'm okay with only allowing ASCII characters in the string if it matters, but I doubt that it does, as Cython seems to favor explicit encoding/decoding.

---

Edit: I have also tried explicit encoding and iterating over a bytestring, which would make sense, but the following code:

```
def func(s, numbers=None):
    if numbers:
         some_dict = numbers
    else:
         some_dict = default
    cdef double m = 0.0
    cdef bytes bs = s.encode('ascii')
    cdef char c
    for c in bs:
        m += some_dict[(<bytes>c).decode('ascii')]
    return m
```

is 3 times slower than my first attempt on Python 2 (close to the speed of the pure Python function) and almost 2 times slower on Python 3.

Comment: There will be almost none speedup in do_stuff is python function. In this case you are just typed loop variable but not the work. Rewrite do_stuff in cython. It would be also helpfull if you provide info what do_stuff does and whats in some_dict values.

Comment: Regarding your KeyError - in C unicode usually maps to int type, so some_dict in this case must be C hash with int keys (or maybe more right Py_UNICODE type). But again, i bet bottleneck is in do_stuff.

Comment: @TurnaevEvgeny `do_stuff` is arithmetics on numbers from `some_dict`. Basically, it's calculating the sum of values from `some_dict` corresponding to keys from `s`. I typed the sum variable, so there is some speedup. So the question is how to cythonize the loop itself.

Comment: It is still alot unclear for me. Post some more code with example data. If you are mapping value to any char in range 255 - then just use array instead of dict. What a func should return?

Comment: @TurnaevEvgeny It's not any char, just a subset of ascii uppercase. But still making a (sparse) array sounds like a sane idea. The value returned is the calculated sum.

Comment: I dont see from examples that func returns sum, also i don't see that do_stuff is returning something. Well yes, array would be much faster if it suits. If you can write C - write the whole func in C "int func(char * str, size_t len)" and when just wrap it in cython. That would be the fastest.

Comment: @TurnaevEvgeny I expanded the code examples. I haven't written in C since forever, but I guess I could put together a simple function like this one.

Answer (score 0):

foo.h

```
// #include <unistd.h>;  // for ssize_t
double foo(char * str, ssize_t str_len, double weights[256]){
    double output = 0.0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < str_len; ++i){
        output += weights[str[i]];
    }
    return output;
}
```

---

```
from cpython.string cimport PyString_GET_SIZE, PyString_Check, PyString_AS_STRING

cdef extern from "foo.h":
    double foo(char * str, ssize_t str_len, double weights[256])   

cdef class Numbers:
    cdef double nums[256]

    def __cinit__(self, py_numbers):
        for x in range(256):
            self.nums[i] = py_numbers[i]

def py_foo(my_str, Numbers nums_inst):
    cdef:
        double res
    # check here my_str is BYTEstring
    if not PyString_Check(my_str):
        raise TypeError("bytestring expected got %s instead" % type(my_str))
    res = foo(PyString_AS_STRING(my_str), PyString_GET_SIZE(my_str), nums_inst.nums)
    return res
```

(untested)

Comment: I would suggest relatively the same if you want hash. But with hashes class Numbers would have C++ map (or any C hash) member.

Comment: This is a very interesting and useful example, thank you. But the missing part about checking what `my_str` is is pretty much what I initially asked, so unfortunately I can't accept the answer yet (although you can count on a +1 from me).

Comment: I just added check, but certainly i wasn't thinking your original question to be about type checking.

Comment: The difference between Python 2.x and 3.x is that type `str` is actually ascii bytestring under 2.x and a unicode string under 3.x, which can be ignored when iterating over an ascii string in pure Python, but got me stuck when moving to Cython.

Comment: Your solution to checking the string type seems to be Python2-specific (although helpful concept-wise). Python 3 API has `PyBytes_Check` and `PyUnicode_Check`. Can I somehow check which of them are defined? Maybe just wrap the import in a `try/except`?

Comment: Sorry i always forget about 3.X, i am stuck with 2.X, you can do what you want with "from cpython.version cimport PY_MAJOR_VERSION" and then "IF PY_MAJOR_VERSION == 3:"